# PHP cant get value from url, im using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^classroom$ dashboard.php?section=classroom [NC]
```

url

```
http://localhost/elearning/classroom?keyword=all
```

php

```
echo $_GET['keyword'];
```

and the problem is why i cant get the value from the url?

can you guys help me to solve this one? Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

When rewriting this URL, the original URL's query string will not be sent to the new URL.
Place your .htaccess inside the elearning directory.

Change

```
RewriteRule ^classroom$ dashboard.php?section=classroom [NC]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^classroom/(\w+)/$ dashboard.php?section=classroom&keyword=$1
```

**Access URL:**

```
http://localhost/elearning/classroom/all/
```

---

[**UPDATE**]

The above idea would work, but there's a standard way of achieving this by adding the **QSA** (Query String Append) flag for your original rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^classroom$ dashboard.php?section=classroom [NC,QSA]
```

that will satisfy your request URL

```
http://localhost/elearning/classroom?keyword=all
```

Comment: thanks for response :)
but it didnt solve anything, and now it get object not found.
why im getting an error 404 like this?

Comment: Where is your dashboard.php? is at the root of the web directory or is it within another directory?

Comment: Are you able to access this URL directly? http://localhost/dashboard.php?section=classroom&keyword=all

Comment: i put dashboard.php on elearning folder, same with the .htaccess file. is there some script that i have to put in .htaccess file?

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. It should work now.

Comment: thanks it works ! but why the css and the jquery didnt called?

Comment: That depends on the location where your CSS and js are located inside the webroot directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62070/discussion-between-kums-and-khrisna-gunanasurya).